# Will memcpy-ing a struct to bytes, and back guarantee the same data even with padding? And interpreting bytes as struct?

Tags: c, memcpy

A very simple example

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t a;
  uint64_t b;
} Test;

// With no struct *packing* sizeof(Test) == 16 on my machine

// Create some data
uint8_t buf[sizeof(Test)];
Test test;
test.a = 255;
test.b = 1234567890;

memcpy(buf, &test, sizeof(Test));

// Now copy the data from buf into a new structure
Test test2;
memcpy(&test2, buf, sizeof(Test));

// Interpret the bytes as a struct Test
Test* test_ptr = (Test*)buf;

// If all of this is done on the same machine (no transmitting data across different sets of hardware)
// are we guaranteed to always have the following conditions
test.a == test2.a;
test.a == test_ptr->a;
test.b == test2.b;
test.b == test_ptr->b;
```

This works on my machine but I am just wondering if it just happens to be an instance of getting lucky with the compiler/architecture. Also what happens if there is a more complicated data structure where there is more padding in different places?

This is all happening on the same machine, so not worrying about sending `buf` over a serial/tcp/etc link and mis-interpreting the bytes.

Comment: Is there a strict aliasing nitpick here, based on `uint8_t` not being a character type?

Comment: Re “This is all happening on the same machine”: Is it between processes? Are there any pointers in the data? Were the programs compiled with the same compiler, including the same settings and anything that could affect structure layout?

Comment: @NateEldredge if `sizeof(uint8_t) == sizeof(char)` there is no strict aliasing issue

Comment: Yes, `if sizeof test` yields 16, `memcpy(buf, &test, sizeof test);` will copy 16 bytes. So it will include padding in your case. Assigning the individual fields *might* not affect the padding if present.

Comment: @0___________: “Character type” does not just mean the size. It has a specific definition in the C standard: `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` (C 2018 6.2.5 15). `uint8_t` might have the same size and representation as `unsigned char` and `char`, but it could be an extended integer type that is not a character type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this interpretation goes too far considering the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil @NateEldredge there are no alising issues. using memcpy . If `sizeof(uint8_t) == sizeof(char)` then allocated buffer will be sufficient to store the structure

Comment: Isn't accessing members of Test via '(Test*)buf' an example of violation of strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @0___________ might know the correct answer but I thought this type of aliasing can be done with char/uint8/unsigned char

Comment: And I guess a more serious problem is that `buf` may not have the necessary alignment for type `Test`, so dereferencing `test_ptr` is UB for that reason alone.

Comment: `Test* test_ptr = (Test*)buf;` if a problem. `memcpy` or union punning needed

Comment: So there is a big difference between your tests like `test.a == test2.a;` (guaranteed to evaluate to 1) and `test.a == test_ptr->a;` (undefined behavior both because of strict aliasing, I believe, as well as alignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed as the memory layout of the different objects having the same type has to be identical.

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t a;
  uint64_t b;
} Test;

Test t1, t2;
uint8_t buf[sizeof(Test)];
t1.a = 255;
t2.b = 1234567890;

memcpy(buf, &t1, sizeof(t1));

memcpy(&t2, buf, sizeof(t2));
```

`t2` & `t1` will have identical memory footprint.

> This is all happening on the same machine, so not worrying about
> sending buf over a serial/tcp/etc link and mis-interpreting the bytes.

If on the both sides of the link you will have the same program (ie compiled using the same compiler & compile options) it will be safe.

Otherwise it is not safe and data has to be serialized.

PS. I have missed one thing:

```
// Interpret the bytes as a struct Test
Test* test_ptr = (Test*)buf;
```

it is pointer pointer punning and it is an UB. Use `memcpy` or union punning instead.

Do not be afraid of `memcpy` as compiler will in most cases optimize it out and this assignment or punning will be done very efficient way.

Comment: When you say the same program on both sides, would this 'guarantee' apply to a 64 bit machine sending to a 32 bit? Or only if the architecture is the same? X86->X86, not X86-ARM. 
And there is obviously endian issues but that's pretty rare in my field (almost all intel or ARM devices), all little endian

Comment: @user2840470 if you can run 64 bits program on 32-bit machine then yes. But I think it is not possible. Otherwise you will have to compile the same source code using different compiler options (assuming the same compiler) and this case is clearly covered in my answer. Same if you have different architectures on both sides - you also will use different compilers/compiler options to build the program